# How can I create documentation with links of java.util (original documentation)

Tags: java, arraylist, collections, documentation

I have a java file. And I want to use with java documentation for methods and etc.
If my some method using with java classes or interfaces, for example:
`Collection<MyClass> names = new ArrayList<>();` how can I linked the Collection or ArrayList of original java.util documentation?

for example: If I Generate the following code to Javadoc , it's present in HTML 
doc, but not linked to ArrayList of java.util.

```
/**
 * The constructor using with {@link Collection} - interface and {@link ArrayList} - class for initialize....
 *
 */
public myConstructor(){
   names = new ArrayList<>();
   ........
}
```

Thanks for help.

Comment: You have any warnings when generating javadoc ?

Comment: No warnings, but when document executed, the words ArrayList or Collection isn't a linked, they are a text data

Answer (score 4):

You need to pass the additional external documentation via the `-link` command line option to the `javadoc` tool, e.g. `-link https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/`.

The links should then be inserted, provided the classes are imported or fully qualified.

Example:

```
import java.util.Collection;

/**
 * {@link java.util.ArrayList} is a {@link Collection}.
 */
public class MyClass {
}
```

```
javadoc -link https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/ MyClass.java
```

Relevant part of the result:

```html
<a href="https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/ArrayList.html?is-external=true" title="class or interface in java.util"><code>ArrayList</code></a> is a <a href="https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Collection.html?is-external=true" title="class or interface in java.util"><code>Collection</code></a>.
```

Comment: @morris added an example